# Finding a certain point in a string and printing the rest

Tags: c#

I'm trying to take a part of a string that I need but I don't need the rest (for this portion)

Basically, the string looks like this:

`This item costs $1.99`

I need that full description elsewhere, but in one particular part in the code, I need it to only display anything after `$` so that it would only print out

`$1.99`

I'm not sure how to do this, could I get some assistance?

Comment: Your string has _always_ one `$` character?

Comment: That is correct, always just the one

Comment: select an answer to say if this can be closed. Keep SO clean, and let us not inflate unanswered question count

Comment: @Krishna my bad, I couldn't make an answer when I wanted to and then ended up forgetting. Sorry!

Comment: np - one day SO has all questions answered :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) and [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods like;

```
var s = "This item costs $1.99";
int index = s.IndexOf("$");
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(index)); // $1.99
```

Basically, we found the index number of first `$` character in the string and get the rest of that string starts with that position.

Comment: omit the + 1 if you want to print $1.99

Answer (score 3):

Here you are. Using regular expression:

`\$` for $ sign, `\d` for digit, `\d+` for 1 or more digit, `\.` for dot

```
var input = "This item costs $1.99 and $0.5 for tax";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\$\d+\.\d+");
for(var i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(matches[i].Value); // $.199, $0.5
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
string ls = "This item costs $1.99"
dollarvalue = "$" + ls.split('$').Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to match *everything* after the $

```
public string GetSubstring(string value) {
    Regex regex = new Regex("\$.*");
    return regex.Match(value);
}
```